# Content in one bootstrap 4 column moves when content in adjacent column is longer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

New to Bootstrap and my first post here. I am trying to build a website template using Bootstrap 4. I have run into an issue where the vertical navbar in left column moves down when I add long text content in adjacent column. How do I prevent the navbar from shifting? It appears that is tries to center itself vertically within the column. The two columns are in the same row ("middle"), respectively `col-3` and `col-9`.

```css
body,
td,
th {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
}

body {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #386890;
}

.container {
  width: 1500px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: medium;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #386890;
}

.col-xl-12 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.banner {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.middle {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.col-xl-3 {
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #386890;
}

.nav {
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #386890;
}

.col-xl-9 {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.footer {
  align-self: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.nav-pills {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #386890;
}

.nav-pills .axtive {
  background-color: #16F804;
}

.nav-pills a:hover {
  color: #386890;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.nav-pills a {
  color: #386890;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.nav-pills li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav-pills ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-size: 75%;
  color: #386890;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ADB2BD;
}

.socialmedia {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!--middle section navbar and main begin-->
<middle class="row middle" style="margin-right: 1px;">

  <!--nav bar start-->

  <nav class="col-xl-3 navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light" style="margin-right: -15px;">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_navbar">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            </span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_navbar" Style="float:top">

      <ul class="nav-pills nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">ACG Blog</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Consulting</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Multimedia</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a> </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">S&T Missions</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a> </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <!--nav bar end-->

  <!--main content section start-->
  <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="EditRegion_page_content" -->

  <main class="col-xl-9">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Molestie nunc non blandit massa. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Cursus eget nunc
    scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra.
    <p>Pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a
      diam maecenas sed enim ut. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. </p>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Molestie nunc non blandit massa. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Cursus eget nunc
    scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra.
    <p>Pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a
      diam maecenas sed enim ut. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. </p>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Molestie nunc non blandit massa. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Cursus eget nunc
    scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra.
    <p>Pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a
      diam maecenas sed enim ut. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. </p>

  </main>

  <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
  <!--nav bar end-->

</middle>
<!--middle section navbar and main end-->
```

Comment: you are using bootstrap library or using CSS of bootstrap classes. if you are using bootstrap library then you can use its classes and change its css acc. to your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `.navbar` has the flex property `align-items: center` set (BootStrap default).

If an element has `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row`, `align-items` aligns the children elements to the cross axis, in this case, `#main_navbar` to the vertical center. (If `flex-direction` was column, then the `align-items:center` would center horizontally).

What you can do, is override BootStrap's code, by adding: `align-items: flex-start` to the `.navbar` element.

This is what I added to your code below:

```
.middle .navbar {
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

I added the `.middle` selector as well, to make sure that it was more specific than just `.navbar` and will override BS styles.

```css
body,
td,
th {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
}

body {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #386890;
}

.container {
  width: 1500px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: medium;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #386890;
}

.col-xl-12 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.banner {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.middle {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.col-xl-3 {
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #386890;
}

.nav {
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #386890;
}


/* ADDED THIS - added .middle to make sure it's more specific than BS */

.middle .navbar {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.col-xl-9 {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.footer {
  align-self: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.nav-pills {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #386890;
}

.nav-pills .axtive {
  background-color: #16F804;
}

.nav-pills a:hover {
  color: #386890;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.nav-pills a {
  color: #386890;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.nav-pills li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav-pills ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-size: 75%;
  color: #386890;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ADB2BD;
}

.socialmedia {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!--middle section navbar and main begin-->
<middle class="row middle" style="margin-right: 1px;">

  <!--nav bar start-->

  <nav class="col-xl-3 navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light" style="margin-right: -15px;">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_navbar">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            </span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_navbar" Style="float:top">

      <ul class="nav-pills nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">ACG Blog</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Consulting</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Multimedia</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a> </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">S&T Missions</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a> </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <!--nav bar end-->

  <!--main content section start-->
  <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="EditRegion_page_content" -->

  <main class="col-xl-9">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Molestie nunc non blandit massa. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Cursus eget nunc
    scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra.
    <p>Pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a
      diam maecenas sed enim ut. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. </p>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Molestie nunc non blandit massa. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Cursus eget nunc
    scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra.
    <p>Pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a
      diam maecenas sed enim ut. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. </p>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Molestie nunc non blandit massa. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Cursus eget nunc
    scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra.
    <p>Pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a
      diam maecenas sed enim ut. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. </p>

  </main>

  <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
  <!--nav bar end-->

</middle>
<!--middle section navbar and main end-->
```